# Converting USB traffic to Ethernet to avoid a long cable run

Tags: windows, networking, usb, ethernet, serial-port

I have an industrial computer cabinet ("near cabinet") to which Ethernet cable has already been run.

Because of an oversight in the design of the system, a proprietary interface module that needs to communicate with the computer in the near cabinet must be installed. This module would get power from and communicate over a small run of USB cable with the Windows computer inside this cabinet.

The problem is that we must run RS-485 from a distant cabinet to this cabinet for the interface module to read industrial sensors, or we must move the interface module itself to the distant cabinet with a long run of USB cable to the computer in the cabinet. Either way, we have to disassemble a bunch equipment and add some kind of long cable run.

If I put the interface module in the distant cabinet, is there a way to convert or piggyback the USB communications (typically showing up as a serial connection on COM3 or COM4) to Ethernet, so I can use the existing Ethernet run and not have to add any home runs of cable?

I have seen devices called USB device servers and USB print servers that seem like they may work, but I don't know if that's what I'm looking for.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: USB over IP is a thing, but maybe not in a way that is useful to you. It’s probably a lot easier to do Serial over IP. I cannot offer a complete solution though, sorry.

Comment: W/o knowing the exact models will be very hard even to speculate. But you can try something like: https://www.waveshare.com/rs485-to-eth.htm